# Android volley: how to handle the error response

Tags: android, exception, android-volley

I implemented an android app with volley library to connect my database. The connection with 'get' and 'post' request it works, but the servers response not working.
This happens because the Error Response catch automatically the errors (for example my server response with code 201 for the login successful, but volley untersand it like error).

I override the parseNetworkError from the class Request:

```
 @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        String parsed;
        NetworkResponse networkResponse = volleyError.networkResponse;
        if(networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
            try {
                parsed = new String(networkResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(networkResponse.headers));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var4) {
                parsed = new String(networkResponse.data);
            }
            NetworkResponse response = new NetworkResponse(networkResponse.data);
            Response<String> parsedResponse;
            switch(response.statusCode){
                case 204:                        
                    ...
                case 401:
                    ...
                default:
                    return volleyError;
            }
        }

        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }
```

The problem is the VolleyError. This class extends Exception and not contains the information (code error).

How can i solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953519/volley-exception-error-when-response-code-304-and-200 I hope this may help you

Comment: I had the same problem. I checked my back-end but I realized information is not returned inside request body.

Answer (score 9):

you can handle like this

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
    // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
    // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
    // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
    if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
    //handle your network error here.
    } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
    //handle if server error occurs with 5** status code
    } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
    //handle if authFailure occurs.This is generally because of invalid credentials
    } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
    //handle if the volley is unable to parse the response data.
    } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
    //handle if no connection is occurred
    } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
    //handle if socket time out is occurred.
    }

}
```

Comment: `ClientError` class not found in volley library. ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using in my projects:

```
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
            if (cm != null) {
                activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            }
            if(activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server is not connected to internet.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your device is not connected to internet.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError || error.getCause() instanceof ConnectException 
                || (error.getCause().getMessage() != null 
                && error.getCause().getMessage().contains("connection"))){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your device is not connected to internet.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (error.getCause() instanceof MalformedURLException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bad Request.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (error instanceof ParseError || error.getCause() instanceof IllegalStateException
                || error.getCause() instanceof JSONException
                || error.getCause() instanceof XmlPullParserException){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Parse Error (because of invalid json or xml).", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (error.getCause() instanceof OutOfMemoryError){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Out Of Memory Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "server couldn't find the authenticated request.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError || error.getCause() instanceof ServerError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server is not responding.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException
                || error.getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException 
                || error.getCause() instanceof SocketException
                || (error.getCause().getMessage() != null 
                && error.getCause().getMessage().contains("Connection timed out"))) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection timeout error", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An unknown error occurred.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String message=null;
            if(error instanceof NetworkError)
            {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                Toast.makeText(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(error instanceof ServerError)
            {
                message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
                Toast.makeText(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
                Toast.makeText(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            HideSwipeDialog();

        }
```

Best Way To Show the Error in Volley Response But Don't put the direct msg to end user be  creative and show msg something like this "Wait For The Moment We Connect To Server"