# Volley Cache returns null when receiving 304

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, android-networking

I am trying to get `Volley` to work using its `Cache`. When I receive a `304` `getCacheEntry().data` is `null` even though `"cache-control"` is set. Here is what I am doing:

1. `Volley` gets instantiated likes this

   ```
   // Instantiate the cache
   Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(c.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB cap

   // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
   Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

   // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
   mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

   // Start the queue
   mRequestQueue.start();
   ```
2. After sending a GET request I get the response `200` with `"cache-control"` set to `"max-age=180, public"`. So far so good right?
3. If a GET request gets made twice or more I set `"If-Modified-Since"` with the last timestamp the request was made to the request header.
4. The second time I request a specific API endpoint the sever will respond with a `304`. `getCacheEntry().data` returns `null` though. If I check the `cache entries` in `Volleys` `RequestQueue` I cannot find an entry for my specific request.

What am I doing wrong? For some reason I have one request that is always cached when fired once. It's even one that returns a lot of data. But all other requests aren't cached. Following code snippet parses the response and checks for `304`.

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response, String charset) { 
    try {
        String json = "";
        if (!response.notModified) {
            json = new String(response.data, charset);
        } else {
            //if not modified -> strangely getCacheEntry().data always null
            json = new String(getCacheEntry().data, charset);
        }
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: If your request is a POST request, IMO you can read the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953519/volley-exception-error-when-response-code-304-and-200

Comment: Thanks @BNK it is a GET request though

Comment: If the server is published in Internet, pls post the url so that I can check tomorrow

Comment: IMO, you can set breakpoint at `Cache.Entry entry = mCache.get(request.getCacheKey());` inside `run` of `CacheDispatcher` first to see if it null or not, this line will run before you got 304 from server

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your cache entry is always null (not only when getting 304 resp code), because of the following:

```
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(c.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB cap
```

Please check your `c.getCacheDir()` to see if you want to use External Storage to store cache data, then you should set `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I solved this issue! `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is set in `AndroidManifest.xml`. But in some old legacy class we generated a new `RequestQueue` for some strange reason ... now it's working. Thank you for your help!!