# Android Volley Cache on LastModified

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley

The server returns a "Last Modified" header based on when the data changes. Need to use this to cache the response in volley.

My Volley request looks something like this:

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
                    callback.onSuccess(result);
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    callback.onSuccess(new JSONArray());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Can find examples to cache based on a fixed time - say cache for 5 mins:
[Android Setup Volley to use from Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-setup-volley-to-use-from-cache)

But this doesnt solve my purpose. The server response has to be invalidated based on the "Last Modified" header. So I'm expecting volley to make the request and get a 304 Not Modified response and hence serve the content from the cache.

Even tried a custom header parser something like this: 
https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java

But this doesnt seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Do you searching for this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953519/volley-exception-error-when-response-code-304-and-200

Comment: For your purpose `So I'm expecting volley to make the request and get a 304 Not Modified response and hence serve the content from the cache`, I think you should use Googe's Volley library instead of mcxiaoke's library. You can set breakpoint and debug, please read at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#103